# an English proverb meaning "the good suffer with the bad"

Tags: translation, proverbs

In my native language, when we want to describe a situation in which a group of people suffer a special consequence regardless of how they performed or whether they deserve that or not, we say "(When fire comes,) wet and dry will burn together" meaning it doesn't matter whether there are dead branches or green branches, in case of a big fire all will burn. What we mean is 'the good suffer with the bad.'

For example,

A couple of students were shouting when the head teacher stepped in. He looked at us angrily and snarled,"next time I hear a sound, I'll send you all home, remember '(when fire comes,) wet and dry will burn together'"

Another example,

The priest told us that it is not enough to be just a good man and we should warn others against their bad deeds because in case of God's wrath, 'wet and dry will burn together'.

Comment: I think *We're all in the same boat* may work, but it has a different connotation from your "wet and dry will burn together" if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Is the word "(tree) branches" implied in this saying?

Comment: Maybe the teacher might also say "[I will err on the side of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/err_on_the_side_of) severity".

Comment: @CowperKettle: by wet and dry, we mean dead (having no water in tissues) branches and green (having water in tissues) branches. So yes actually what we literally mean is that (in case of a big fire) all braches (whether dead or green) get burnt.

Comment: @Damkerng T.: It can be a good equivalent for second context I provided provided that the person saying this considers himself as a sufferer too. I think teacher cann't say "we're in the same boat" because he won't be one of the people who will suffer if a student keeps being noisy. Can the teacher say, "Remember, YOU're all in the same boat" ?

Comment: I can't think of something like this no matter how hard I try. I think the general concept of the good suffering with the bad is so reprehensible in our culture that a proverb of this nature would be difficult to come by and definitely wouldn't be common. In your last example, we'd simply call the teacher unjust at best and flat out evil at worst.

Comment: @Azad *You're all in the same boat* might work, but I would go for *You're all in this together*. It's not a proverb, though.

Comment: I can't think of any other proverb except what @DamkerngT. suggested. It sits very well in your case. Still, if you want something close to that, I have something to suggest. This is not a proverb, probably it is, but it can be clearly understood: ***When the buffaloes fight, crops suffer.***

Comment: Is there always the sense of **punishment** meted out indiscriminately? Or could one use this proverb to say that those who are ecologically conscious will suffer along with those who are not as a result of climate change?

Comment: @TRomano: Actually, the point of this saying is when something bad happens, it doesn't matter whether you have been a good person or bad person. Yes, as you said it can be used for something that is completely unrelated to punishment. For example, "in this drought, 'wet and dry got burnt' farmers lost their crops, and ranchers their cattle'. But mostly there is a sense of indiscriminate punishment involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are idioms rather than proverbs.

For punishment specifically:

> punishing all for the acts of one

For unfairly blaming a whole group of people for the problems caused by some, you can say that the group were

> tarred with the same brush

For death, you can say

> We all go the same way

Comment: I guess I can use a couple of phrases and idioms that you mentioned to fit in different situations where I think I should use my native proverb because the meaning is more inclusive. Thank you all for your help. 